# php(7.0) をインストールした apache(2.4.16)のhttpd.exe起動時に、「VCRUNTIME140.dllがない」というエラーが起こる

Tags: php, windows, apache

apache(2.4.16)のhttpd.exe起動時に、下記画像の通り「VCRUNTIME140.dllがない」というエラーが起こります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

現在の調査状況として、
・VC2013のVisualC++再頒布可能パッケージインストール→インストール済み
・php(7.0)のインストール→php.exe起動時「VCRUNTIME140.dllがない」エラー発生
を試してみましたが、解決していない状況です。

解決方法の分かるかたがいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php 7.0 は Visual C++ 2015 ランタイムが必要だったと思います。

なお、Visual Studio の バージョン "14" は Visual Studio 2015 ですので
`VCRUNTIME140.dll` の 140 = version 14.0 → 2015 のランタイムという意味だと思います。

（間違っていたらごめんなさい）

Comment: 解決することが出来ました。ありがとうございます。